# The probability that $n$ items out of $m$ selected turn out to be of a particular kind

Tags: probability

> A parking lot contains 100 cars, $k$ of which happen to be lemons. We select $m$ of these cars at random and take them for a test drive. Find the probability that $n$ of the cars tested turn out to be lemons.

I understand what the sample space of the question is ${100 \choose m}$, but I don't understand how they find the number of outcomes ${k \choose n}\cdot{100-k \choose m-n}$.

[Here is a picture of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emKVq.jpg)

Comment: Have you read about the Hypergeometric distribution? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 1):

What's the probability of choosing exactly $m$ cars at random and exactly $n$ of them turn out to be lemons, knowing there $k$ lemons in the whole lot?

There are ${k\choose n}$ ways to pick $n$ lemons out of $k$. We know that we picked exactly $m$ cars, so the rest of the sample $m-n$ must have been actual cars. How many actual cars are in the whole lot? There are $100 - k$; thus, there are ${100-k\choose m-n}$ ways to choose $m-n$ actual cars out of $100-k$.

Hence the sought probability is $$\frac{{k\choose n}{100-k\choose m-n}}{{100\choose m}}$$

Comment: Btw, you must be quite blind to not be able to distinguish lemons from actual cars at first sight.

Comment: I wondered about that too, possibly a misspelling of "limos"?